# Creating a Simple Layout/Style Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, editor, wysiwyg

I am trying to create a layout/style editor similar to what is available on blogger. I noticed that they use an iframe, but the iframe has to refresh everytime you make a change. I am looking to do something more responsive. For example, if i change the width of a div I would like to see this change happening while I move the slider.

I was wondering if something like this is possible with the iframe setup using jquery/etc to modify the source of what is in the iframe, or is it better to not use an iframe?

The iframe would be used to load an existing webpage that is online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good thing with an iframe is that is not interfeering the rest of the page (you can use diffrent CSS, scripts, variable names and so on). TinyMCE and other editors uses iframe for its content. And yes its possible to access the iframe directly from jQuery:

See this link, http://jsbin.com/ajatix/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for the extra information. The iframe would be used to load an exisiting webpage in it. Does that change your answer?

Comment: It depends if the webpage is on the same domain or if its not. www.example.com cannot load www.example2.com into an iframe and modify the content thru script. The browser will deny access

Comment: Hi Simon, so if I have a page on www.site.com which loads www.site.com/page.php into an iframe, I will be able to edit the css/contents displayed in the iframe?

Comment: Yes, I did a shitty example, wait 5 secound and you will see that the content is modifyd from the parent: http://jsbin.com/ajatix/3/edit